# Wallis integral and gamma function

Tags: integration, factorial, pi

I would like to ask if anyone would help me to explain how to reach the following relation.
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \left( 1-x^{\frac{1}{p}} \right)^q dx= \frac{p!\,q!}{(p+q)!}
\end{equation}
If we substitute one half for p and q
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1 \sqrt{ 1-x^2} dx = \frac{\pi}{4}
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\frac{p!\,q!}{(p+q)!} \rightarrow (1/2)!^2 \rightarrow (1/2)! = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
\end{equation}
I just proved that one half of the factorial is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: We are not allowed to use Beta function? Because it would be trivial if we let $x=t^p$ to get
$p \int_0^1 (1-t)^q t^{p-1} dt$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the substitution $x=t^p$ to get
\begin{eqnarray*}
p \int_0^1 t^{p-1}(1-t)^q dt.
\end{eqnarray*}
This is the beta function ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: But the beta function is defined $\int_{0}^{1} t^{p-1} (1-t)^{q}\,dt$, what about p in the front.

Comment: In wiki they give
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1} dt = \frac{(x-1)!(y-1)!}{(x+y-1)!}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 t^{p-1}(1-t)^{q} dt = \frac{(p-1)!(q)!}{(p+q)!}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply this by $p$ and the result follows.

Comment: Thank you very much.